# Will my app be rejected if it uses the "aluminum look" for its icon?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I have created a nice icon for my app that quite accurately reproduces the style of Apple's Aluminum logos (ex. iCloud, etc.)

In reading the app review guidelines, I noticed this:

> ### 8 - Trademarks and trade dress
>
> 8.1 Apps must comply with all terms and conditions explained in the Guidelines for Using Apple Trademarks and Copyrights and the Apple Trademark List.
>
> 8.2 Apps that suggest or infer that Apple is a source or supplier of the app, or that Apple endorses any particular representation regarding quality or functionality will be rejected
>
> 8.3 Apps which appear confusingly similar to an existing Apple product or advertising theme will be rejected
>
> 8.4 Apps that misspell Apple product names in their app name (i.e., GPS for Iphone, iTunz) will be rejected
>
> 8.5 Use of protected 3rd party material (trademarks, copyrights, trade secrets, otherwise proprietary content) requires a documented rights check which must be provided upon request
>
> 8.6 Google Maps and Google Earth images obtained via the Google Maps API can be used within an application if all brand features of the original content remain unaltered and fully visible. Apps that cover up or modify the Google logo or copyright holders identification will be rejected

In particular 8.3 seems to say that you can't look too much like an apple product.

Will my app be rejected?

Comment: I've rejected your question.  Please ask on a business/legal site.

Comment: Questions about the app review process are very common here and relevant.  Within reason, they are usually fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of apps that have aluminum icons.  You'll probably be fine.  But it is Apple.  You never know.  And changing the icon if they don't like it isn't a big deal.  See what happens.

Comment: thanks. I understand its not just a yes or no question. so I appreciate your opinion! And you're right it is an easy fix. just wanted to make sure it wasnt an instant rejection basically. cheers.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to tell for sure until you submit the app for review.  Nobody can tell you what will happen except the people doing the reviews at Apple and you won't find that out until you submit it.  I would submit it and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks. appreciate the answer. you're right. only one way to really find out!